# Help understanding unipolar transfer function

Tags: math, function, neural-network, algebra

There is a question I am stuck on using the following formula for the unipolar transfer function:

```
f(net)=     1
         __________
               -net
         1 + e
```

The example has the following:

```
out =        1
        ____________  = 0.977
               -3.75
        1 + e
```

How do we arrive at 0.977?

What is e?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*e* = 2.71828... is the [base of natural logarithms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e&a=*C.e-_*NamedConstant-). It's a mathematical constant that comes up in many different equations, similar to *π*. You will see it all the time when doing exponents and logarithms.

[Plug it into your equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/%281%2Be%5E-3.75%29) and you get 0.977.

Answer (score 3):

While factually correct the other responses merely provide the value of e and confirm the underlying computation.  This type of [**sigmoid functions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is so ubiquitous to neural networks that some additional insight may be welcome.

Essentially the exponential function (e to the x power),  has a very characteristic curve:

- Mostly flat at zero (very slightly above zero, actually),  from - infinity to about  -2
- incrementally sharp turn towards the vertical, between about -2 and +4
- quasi "vertical", with values in excess of 150 and increasingly huge, from +5 to infinity

As a result **exponential curves are very useful for producing "S-shaped" functions**; BTW, "S" is Sigma in Greek which supplied the etymology for "*sigmoid*". Such functions are often patterned on the formula shown in the question:

```
 1/(1 + e^-x)
```

where x is the variable.  Typically such functions also include constants aimed at stretching the range (the input zone where changes in x are significant) and/or at modifying the curve in this middle zone.
The result of such functions is that up to a particular value of the input, the function is quasi constant, then, for a particular range of inputs, the function provides a increasing output, and finally past the upper value of the range, the function is quasi constant.  Also looking in more details, such Sigmoids have a point of inflection which correspond to a reversing of the rate of change of the ouptut and which also marks an area of the curve, on either side, where the changes are the slowest, relatively.

In turn, **such S-shaped curves (1) are very useful to normalize the output of neural network neurons**, or more generally, to normalize various numeric values during processes of various nature.  Intuitively these correspond to a "***sweet spot***" or a "***sweet range***" of the underlying neuron or device.

(1) Or also, possibly,  "step-down" shaped curves, i.e. curves with a mostly constant high value, a decreasing value within the mid-range, and a low mostly constant value thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

e is [Euler's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) == 2.718281828....

If you raise e to the -3.75 power, add one to it, and take the inverse, you'll get precisely 0.977022630....

Answer (score 1):

'e' is the base for the natural logarithm function, the value of which is equivalent to the sum of the infinite series 1/n! for n from 0 to infinity. It is available in the C standard library or the java Math package as the exp() function.

If you evaluate 1/(1+exp(-3.75)) you will get 0.977